# Accessing an Ebean Model List - Java PlayFramework without converting to JSON

Tags: java, playframework

I have a list from model below

```
public static List<PropertyMst> propertyMstList(){
    return new ArrayList<>(PropertyMst.find.where().eq("isactive",true).findList());

}
```

When I run it from my controller I get the below output

```
application - Print Total Properties[models.PropertyMst@1, models.PropertyMst@3]
```

I'm able to convert this to JSON.

How do I go about accessing the models properties e.g propertyMst.id = 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PropertyMst propertyMst = PropertyMst.propertyMstList().get(0);
```

Then you can get all the properties of the model from propertyMst